# How to connect to the microsoft band with band sdk without the microsoft health app on my android to get real time data

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, real-time-data, microsoft-band

I want to develop an android app to get real time sensor data from my microsoft band through bluetooth.I have successfully paired the band with my android but wasn't able to connect it.I tried using the ms-band-sdk but it needs a microsoft heath app connected to the band.I tried installing some versions of the health app but the apps don't go past the sign in page.Is there any way to have the app connect to the band or bypass the app somehow.

This is the exception that i get when i try to connect to the band using the sdk.

```
com.microsoft.band.BandIOException: Microsoft Health BandService is not bound. Please make sure Microsoft Health is installed and that you have connected to it with the correct permissions.
    at com.microsoft.band.f.a(SourceFile:512)
    at com.microsoft.band.a$a.a(SourceFile:58)
    at com.microsoft.band.a$a.await(SourceFile:2041)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$BandConnectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:33)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$BandConnectTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:26)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```